# Pros & cons of enterprise volatile/stable ERC20 usage and likelihood

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, contract-development, contract-design, tokens

What are the pros and cons for a business to accept a stable/volatile erc20 token as means of payment? and what is the likelihood of such? I assume a business would always prefer a stablecoin over a volatile coin. I'd love to hear people's individual view on this subject.

Comment: "_I'd love to hear people's individual view on this subject._" Eliciting different opinions on a given topic isn't what Stack Exchange is for, as any answers you get are going to be subjective rather than being of a technical, objective nature. A better place to discuss this type of thing is one of the Reddit subreddits - either https://www.reddit.com/r/ethereum or https://www.reddit.com/r/ethdev

Answer (score 1):

All cryptocurrencies tend to be rather volatile except (maybe) some stablecoins. Most likely this situation will change over time but businesses can't wait that long. As you said I would also assume businesses to prefer stable coins/tokens in general.

Or what if the business idea is to accept volatile coins at a discount? So they take a volatile coin as payment at 95% of its value, for example. You could of course claim that why wouldn't the buyer just sell the coin himself but it may not be possible / feasible (due to illiquid market, speed of transactions or something similar).

Or maybe the volatile coins could be kept in an escrow (while receiving the purchased goods already) until their value can be properly established or the original buyer changes them for some less volatile "proper" coin. This way the buyer would probably need to put in more than 100% of the coins based on their value.

Anyway, there's some ideas.

Comment: good input as always :-)